# WPF. Что означает mc:Ignorable="d"  ?

Tags: c#, wpf

WPF. Что означает mc:Ignorable="d"  ?

Comment: Если кто-то сможет ответить на вопрос, поясните это еще
d:DesignHeight="500" d:DesignWidth="300">
Как соотносится. Спасибо.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Из [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15749584/what-mean-mcignorable-d-in-wpf):

> Пространство имён [`mc:Ignorable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa350024.aspx) используется для декларации XAML-кода, который игнорируется парсером XAML.
>
> Это позволяет указывать информацию, которая используется, например, окном дизайнера XAML, и не влияет на поведение программы. В вашем случае, вы можете указать `DesignHeight` и `DesignWidth`, которые не являются "настоящими" свойствами `Window`, а работают лишь при просмотре в дизайнере XAML (чтобы вам было удобнее редактировать).

Comment: Ништяк- 3 минуты время ответа на вопрос.

Comment: @VladD, большое спасибо за перевод. Я собирался перевести, но не успел.

Comment: @alex91: Пожалуйста!